# DB is down while filling it with data

Tags: sql

I have query for DB creation:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Library;
USE Library;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Subscribers
(
    s_id   INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    s_name VARCHAR(150)                                NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Subscriptions
(
    sb_id         INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    sb_subscriber INTEGER UNSIGNED             NOT NULL,
    sb_book       INTEGER UNSIGNED             NOT NULL,
    sb_start      DATE                         NOT NULL,
    sb_finish     DATE                         NOT NULL,
    sb_is_active  ENUM ('Y', 'N')              NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Books
(
    b_id       INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    b_name     VARCHAR(150)                                NOT NULL,
    b_year     SMALLINT UNSIGNED                           NOT NULL,
    b_quantity SMALLINT UNSIGNED                           NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Genres
(
    g_id   INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    g_name VARCHAR(150) UNIQUE                         NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Authors
(
    a_id   INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    a_name VARCHAR(150)                                NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS m2m_books_genres
(
    pfKb_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    pfKg_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY PK_m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS m2m_books_authors
(
    pfKb_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    pfKa_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY PK_m2m_books_authors (pfKb_id, pfKa_id)
);

ALTER TABLE Subscriptions
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_subscriptions_books
        FOREIGN KEY (sb_book)
            REFERENCES Books (b_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Subscriptions
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_subscriptions_subscribers
        FOREIGN KEY (sb_subscriber)
            REFERENCES Subscribers (s_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE m2m_books_genres
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_m2m_books_genres_books
        FOREIGN KEY (pfKb_id)
            REFERENCES Books (b_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE m2m_books_genres
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_m2m_books_genres_genres
        FOREIGN KEY (pfKg_id)
            REFERENCES Genres (g_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE m2m_books_authors
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_m2m_books_authors_authors
        FOREIGN KEY (pfKa_id)
            REFERENCES Authors (a_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE m2m_books_authors
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_m2m_books_authors_books
        FOREIGN KEY (pfKb_id)
            REFERENCES Books (b_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And the query for filling my DB with data:

```
USE library;

INSERT INTO books (b_name, b_year, b_quantity)
VALUES ('Евгений Онегин', 1985, 2);
INSERT INTO books (b_name, b_year, b_quantity)
VALUES ('Сказка о рыбаке и рыбке', 1990, 3);
INSERT INTO books (b_name, b_year, b_quantity)
VALUES ('Основания и империя', 2000, 5);
INSERT INTO books (b_name, b_year, b_quantity)
VALUES ('Психология и программирование', 1998, 1);
INSERT INTO books (b_name, b_year, b_quantity)
VALUES ('Язык программирования С++', 1996, 3);
INSERT INTO books (b_name, b_year, b_quantity)
VALUES ('Курс теоритической физики', 1981, 12);
INSERT INTO books (b_name, b_year, b_quantity)
VALUES ('Искусство программирования', 1993, 7);

INSERT INTO authors (a_name)
VALUES ('Д. Кнут');
INSERT INTO authors (a_name)
VALUES ('А. Азимов');
INSERT INTO authors (a_name)
VALUES ('Л.Д. Ландау');
INSERT INTO authors (a_name)
VALUES ('Е.М. Лифшиц');
INSERT INTO authors (a_name)
VALUES ('Б. Страуструп');
INSERT INTO authors (a_name)
VALUES ('А.С. Пушкин');

INSERT INTO genres (g_name)
VALUES ('Поэзия');
INSERT INTO genres (g_name)
VALUES ('Программирование');
INSERT INTO genres (g_name)
VALUES ('Психология');
INSERT INTO genres (g_name)
VALUES ('Наука');
INSERT INTO genres (g_name)
VALUES ('Классика');
INSERT INTO genres (g_name)
VALUES ('Фантастика');

INSERT INTO subscribers (s_name)
VALUES ('Иванов И.И.');
INSERT INTO subscribers (s_name)
VALUES ('Петров П.П.');
INSERT INTO subscribers (s_name)
VALUES ('Сидоров С.С.');
INSERT INTO subscribers (s_name)
VALUES ('Сидоров С.С.');

INSERT INTO m2m_books_authors (pfKb_id, pfKa_id)
VALUES (1, 7);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_authors (pfKb_id, pfKa_id)
VALUES (2, 7);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_authors (pfKb_id, pfKa_id)
VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_authors (pfKb_id, pfKa_id)
VALUES (4, 3);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_authors (pfKb_id, pfKa_id)
VALUES (4, 6);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_authors (pfKb_id, pfKa_id)
VALUES (5, 6);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_authors (pfKb_id, pfKa_id)
VALUES (6, 5);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_authors (pfKb_id, pfKa_id)
VALUES (6, 4);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_authors (pfKb_id, pfKa_id)
VALUES (7, 1);

INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (2, 5);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (3, 6);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (4, 3);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (6, 5);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (7, 2);
INSERT INTO m2m_books_genres (pfKb_id, pfKg_id)
VALUES (7, 5);

INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (100, 1, 3, 2011 - 01 - 12, 2011 - 02 - 12, 'N');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (2, 1, 1, 2011 - 01 - 12, 2011 - 02 - 12, 'N');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (3, 3, 3, 2012 - 05 - 17, 2012 - 07 - 12, 'Y');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (42, 1, 2, 2012 - 06 - 11, 2012 - 08 - 11, 'N');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (57, 4, 5, 2012 - 06 - 11, 2012 - 08 - 11, 'N');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (61, 1, 7, 2014 - 08 - 03, 2014 - 10 - 03, 'N');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (62, 3, 5, 2014 - 08 - 3, 2014 - 10 - 03, 'Y');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (86, 3, 1, 2014 - 08 - 03, 2014 - 09 - 03, 'Y');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (91, 4, 1, 2015 - 10 - 07, 2015 - 03 - 07, 'Y');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (95, 1, 4, 2015 - 10 - 07, 2015 - 11 - 07, 'N');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (99, 4, 4, 2015 - 10 - 08, 2025 - 11 - 08, 'Y');
```

Long story short, i get this:

*[23000][1452] Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`library`.`m2m_books_authors`, CONSTRAINT `FK_m2m_books_authors_authors` FOREIGN KEY (`pfKa_id`) REFERENCES `authors` (`a_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)*

I know about solution `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` but I want to solve this issue correctly and find out why is this error happens. Thanks yall for any answers, I appreciate it.

Comment: Check the `FK_m2m_books_authors_authors` constraint

Comment: @Tony, I'm creating tables and keys using this diagram. It seems I did everything fine, did I?
Diagram:
[link](https://imgur.com/a/q9jyQXo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have the column `a_id` in the table `authors` as an `IDENTITY` if you look carefully you only inserted 6 authors and you are trying to assign something to author id 7 which might not exists.

Answer (score 0):

If someone will use my code for studying or whatever, one more mistake:

USE THIS:

```
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (100, 1, 3, '2011-01-12', '2011-02-12', 'N');
```

INSTEAD OF THIS:

```
INSERT INTO subscriptions (sb_id, sb_subscriber, sb_book, sb_start, sb_finish, sb_is_active)
VALUES (100, 1, 3, 2011 - 01 - 12, 2011 - 02 - 12, 'N');
```

And, of course, see the @Juanjo reply.